# string not converting to integer

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert `string` to `integer` from a object's property, where i am facing lot of problems.

**1st Method**

```
public class test
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
}

//test.Class value is 150.0
var i = Convert.ToInt32(test.Class);
```

It is saying error that `Input String is not in a correct format`

**2nd Method**

```
int i = 0;
Int32.TryParse(test.Class, out i);
```

The value of the above code is always zero

**3rd Method**

```
int j = 0;
Int32.TryParse(test.Class, NumberStyles.Number, null, out j);
```

Here i am getting the value as `150` correctly but as I am using `null` for `IFormatProvider` Will there be any problem with this?

Which is the proper method for converting string to integer with these cases?

Comment: I would guess in your system decimal separator is ","

Comment: Are you sure you can convert `"150.0"` which is a floating point value to an integer?

Comment: @athabaska, I am not sure about wat u saying? Where to check that? So the answer is?

Comment: @Patashu, Am not sure. Won't we able to convert it?

Comment: @SSS in the remarks for TryParse here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx  notice the string can only contain [whitespace][sign]digits[whitespace].  150.0 contains a period ".", therefore fails.

Comment: @SSS If it was not 150.0 but 150.1 what would you expect to happen? Would it fail? Round down? Round up? Round to nearest?

Comment: Set it to `150`.  `150.0` is not convertible to `int`

Comment: @RobertHarvey, your ans seems funny, what i really need is to convert values to `int`. But you're saying to the value as `int`

Comment: Honestly, you probably should read a book.  I'm not trying to be mean, but this is really basic stuff.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Cool i understood. So is there any fair answer to convert what i need?

Comment: A couple of folks here have already suggested that you parse it as a double and then cast to an int.  Or, you can Split(".") and throw away the fractional part of the numeric text.  I'm a little surprised that the TryParse is actually returning a value.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Ok thanks, yeah the 3rd method actually returning a value what i need but it seems not the proper way

Comment: TryParse does not return a value, it will just return false and leave the out parameter as it was.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen, yeah i meant that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value 150.0 includes *decimal separator* "." and so can't be converted 
directly into any integer type (e.g. Int32). You can obtain the
desired value in two stage conversion: first to double, then to Int32

```
Double d;

if (Double.TryParse(test.Class, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d)) {
  Int32 i = (Int32) d;
  // <- Do something with i
}
else {
  // <- test.Class is of incorrect format
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you sure that `test.class` contains float value than better use this

```
float val= Convert.ToSingle(test.class, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`Convert.ToInt32("150.0") Fails Because It is simply not an integer as the error says quite handsomly`

Comment: it may contain anything like 50, 50.0, 150, 150.0 etc. So i need to convert these value to `int` but not `float`

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7e175yd.aspx): you get a FormatException if "value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9)". Lose the decimal point, or convert to a float and then convert to int.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't convert a 150.0 to an integer, but you can convert it to a Double/Single and then cast it to int.

```
int num = (int)Convert.ToSingle(test.Class) //explicit conversion, loss of information
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b.aspx